# Does BigQuery give exact values on aggregations?

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery

I have read that both Apache Impala and PrestoDB do not give 100% accurate results when doing large aggregations (unless specified manually in the query). Does BigQuery also estimate on large aggregations, or are the numbers exact?

If it is able to achieve exactness, how is this done (and why wouldn't Impala, Presto, or ElasticSearch give exact values on their aggregations?)

Here is what I mean by approximate vs. exact: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_approximate_aggregations.html.

Comment: Please cite your sources for the things you read. Impala != Presto != Elastic

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approximate-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, yes, the results are exact. If you want to know more about some aggregation function you want to use, you can refer to the [BQ docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#aggregate-functions) to confirm how the function behaves.

As an example of a statistical approximation function we have the `count(distinct field)`. If you want to have the exact number, then you should use `exact_count_distinct(field)` (this is also explained in the docs).

And this is done by simply sacrificing performance. If you have some large dataset to play with you can run both `count(distinct)` and `exact_count_distinct` as an example and you will see the considerable differences between responses times.

For the most part though BigQuery is quite fast so depending on the size of your data you can use exact operations and still have your responses in the seconds range.

Comment: Great answer Will

Comment: note that COUNT(DISTINCT) is exact in #standardSQL, but it was approximate in #legacySQL

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery's Standard SQL dialect, all approximate aggregate functions are appropriatelly named, every one of them starts with `APPROX_` prefix (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approximate-aggregate-functions).
Aggregate functions without `APPROX_` prefix in Standard SQL are all exact.

P.S. Functions operating on floating point, such as most statistical functions, may have usual floating point related precision loss.